# Protractor: testing date text with various formats

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

HTML:

```
<div id="date"> {{date | date : 'EEE MMM d HH:mm'}} </div>
```

It displays on the screen at "Tue Sep 30 10:45"

Test:

```
expect(element(by.id('date')).getText()).toBe("Tue Sept 30 10:45");
```

Fails with:

> Expected 'Sep 30, 2014 10:45' to be 'Tue Sep 30 10:45'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to compare `Date` objects, not strings:

```
element(by.id('date')).getText().then(function (value) {
    var dateValue = new Date(value);
    var expectedDateValue = new Date(dateValue.getFullYear(), 9, 30, 10, 45, 0);

    expect(dateValue).toBe(expectedDateValue);
});
```

---

If you want to additionally check the format, you can dive into the wonderful world of regular expressions, or just use the [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) library:

```
element(by.id('date')).getText().then(function (value) {
    expect(moment(value, ["EEE MMM d HH:mm"]).isValid()).toBe(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to compare the value of the data AND the format.  If someone changes the format to something else, the test should fail.  That's why I tried doing it by string.

Comment: The first option is strange.  It's returning: "Expected Date(Sun Sep 30 2001 10:45:00 GMT+0100 (BST))"  On the screen, it's showing 2014...why is this displaying 2001?  The date is 2014 in the database, it's 2014 when I change the html to display yyyy.

Comment: I think it's because it doesn't display the year, so 'getText()' doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Jason okay, updated - setting the year of expected date to the year of the parsed date (I think it is okay here since year is not important). Please check.

Answer (score 0):

https://momentjs.com/ this is very good library that helps to alter date values based on required formats

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // September 1st 2017, 6:56:48 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Friday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Sep 1st 17
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2017 escaped 2017
moment().format();
```

angular.mock.TzDate is a native alternative from angular. this comes as a helper from angular mocks and truly safe guard your test from the system timezone or any other dependencies

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/type/angular.mock.TzDate

this plays well with Jasmine or mocha which can be clubbed with protractor